# Is an array of vectors entirely contiguous memory?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

I know vectors are guaranteed to be contiguous memory, and so are arrays. So what happens when I do something like this:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> my_array[10];
my_array[2].push_back(11);
my_array[2].push_back(7);
```

What would the memory look like? If both need to be contiguous, would every element of the array after `my_array[2]` be pushed forward a byte every time I do a `push_back()` on `my_array[2]`?

Would this be the same situation as when I have an array of structs, where the structs have a member that has a variable size, such as a string or another vector?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Memory footprint of `std::vector` consists of two parts:

- The memory for the `std::vector` object itself (very small, and independent of the size), and
- The memory for the data of the vector (depends on the number of elements in the vector).

The first kind of data will be contiguous in an array; the second kind of data is allocated dynamically, so it would not be contiguous in an array.

This would not be the same as with a C `struct` that has a flexible data member, because the data portion of `std::vector` is not always allocated in the same kind of memory, let alone being adjacent to it. The vector itself may be allocated in static, dynamic, or automatic memory areas, while its data is always in the dynamic area. Moreover, when vector is resized, the memory for its data may be moved to a different region.

Each time you call `push_back`, `std::vector` checks if it has enough dynamic memory to accommodate the next data element. If there is not enough memory, then the vector allocates a bigger chunk of memory, and moves its current content there before pushing the new item.

Comment: I see. What would happen if I had an array of structs that had string members? Strings don't have the same footprint you described, do they? That is, the string object actually holds the data.

Comment: @Daniel Although the standard does not say what needs to happen in case of strings, the implementation is often the same as with vectors. There are implementations that keep the data of short strings (a few characters) within the string itself, but for longer strings all implementations use dynamic memory store. `std::array` keeps its data inline, but you must specify its size at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

The vector memory structure is contiguous in memory; however std::vector's all contain a pointer pointing to dynamically allocated memory for the actual storage (which is very very likely not contiguous).

Knowing this, std::vector::push_back will only check to see if the (external) dynamically allocated array has enough capacity to hold the new item, if not it will reallocate space. A push_back on the first vector that overflows will not cause the second vector in the array to reallocate memory, that isn't how it works.

Also, there is no such thing as a struct having a variable size, the size of structures and classes have to be known at compile time.

std::string also has a fixed size, although you may think it is variable, because it also (like vector) has a pointer to the `char*` it contains.

Comment: I see. From "std::vector's all contain a pointer pointing to dynamically allocated memory for the actual storage (which is very very likely not contiguous)", you mean that the storage of two vectors won't necessarily be contiguous with each other, correct? Because even in the heap, a single vector's storage should be entirely contiguous, right?

Comment: yes, a single vector's storage is always contiguous in the heap. However if you have 2 std::vector's aligned with each other in memory, their storage pointers are very likely not contiguous.